# Brown foamy water in GE softener

Tags: water-softener

I just cleaned my GE softener tank and put in 3 bags of salt pellets and added 3 gallons of water. Next morning I take a look and saw a lot of foammy [image]water and a brownish mix. No salt pellets visible. Water almost to the top of tank  this right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using regular, "cheaper", rock salt instead of ones labeled for water softner use, those salts contain a lot of dirt which will produce the same results you are experiencing. Part of the problem could also be from the water itself.

Comment: Cheap salt combined with hard water I would say brown foam is normal.

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that one of the black hoses was bent, so most likely all of the discharged water was coming back to the tank!!! As you can see, the tank was almost full of water!!!